# Executing wget via PHP

Tags: php, bash, unix, wget

I'm using the wget command from within php to download a css stylesheet and its dependencies.

```
exec ("wget -p --convert-links -nH -nd --no-check-certificate http://infidelphia.com/style.css -P /home/devuser/public_html/Tset/");
```

There is a stylesheet and a couple of images. When I execute it in the command line:

```
wget -p --convert-links -nH -nd --no-check-certificate http://infidelphia.com/style.css -P /home/devuser/public_html/Tset/
```

I see there is a 404 for one of the resources in between but everything else after it downloads fine.

But when I execute this via PHP everything after this resource is skipped. Is there any way to make sure that failed downloads/errors are skipped over and rest of the assets can be downloaded?

Comment: Is necessary to use wget to download files?

Comment: Well I don't know of any other way, do you know of any ? Ofcourse I am talking in context of a PHP Script. I need to download via the script.

Comment: See my answer. I hope it is useful

Comment: find the path to the wget that works from cmd line with `which wget`. Then edit your php to use the same path for wget, and see if that fixes the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, i use php curl to download files, for example:

```
$rutaArchivo = '/home/devuser/public_html/Tset/style.css';
$urlArchivo = 'http://infidelphia.com/style.css';

$fp = fopen ($rutaArchivo, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($urlArchivo);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$this->httpCode = $httpCode;

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

if ($httpCode != 200) {
    unlink($rutaArchivo);
    echo 'Download error, deleting the empty file';    
} else {
    echo 'Download ok';
}
```

Greatings!

Comment: But that won't get me the dependencies (images etc) like wget.

Comment: What about if you read style.css and with regular expresion gets de images path, font path, etc. and then download each file ?